# Detect CME or XPM with Anguilla

Tags: experience-manager, cme, gui-extensions

Is there any command with Anguilla Javascript Framework that allows us to know if we are working in XPM or CME in order to execute different commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
$display.getWindow().$config.CurrentEditor
```

It returns: "CME" or "SiteEdit".

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice find! I'm sure I've seen people ask this in the past. By the way, I believe that can be simplified to $config.CurrentEditor

Comment: That it's true!